# Native way to read smart card from browser without an applet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, smartcard

I'm developing a Rails app, and in some moment the users will need to use a smart card for authenticating into the app. I know how to implement this using a Java applet, but I was wondering if there exists a native way of doing this using the browser and avoid using an applet. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option to interact with a client device (like a smart card) using the browser is to use a separate container, such as Java applets, Flash, Silverlight or native browser extensions.

Comment: I'm finally using an applet in oder to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read this: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSL client certificate authentication (which is the best option when considering smart cards for webapp authentication, anyway) you can rely on the built-in support in browsers, given that you have proper drivers present for your card(s) on client machines.